# How does CiviEvent Facebook "like" works?

Tags: civievent, facebook

I was testing the behavior of the "FB like" in the event subscription form.
It seems not to work, and anyway, how can it point the event page if there is not in the DB the data keeping the FB event URL?
Looking at the page source. the link is the following:

https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=240719639306341&href=http.....

But this does not help me, I am very confused on how it can work.
Can someone show me the light?

Thanks

Marcello

Answer (score 1):

the facebook like embed a widget from facebook in the page, that (beside spying on your visitors, or anywhere that contains that button) knows on which page it's embedded and therefore what to like

What do you mean by it doesn't work?

it has nothing to do with the event you might have created on facebook, it's only about the civicrm page on your website that describes the event

Comment: Hi Xavier,
I try to be more detailed.
I creared an Event and checked the "Allow sharing through social media?" box.

Comment: ... continue

So when CiviCRM generate the subsciption form, there is a FB button, I clicked the button an put a comment. But:
-1)no new news appear in my personal FB page after this operation
2) I don't understand what's the event I gave my "like", infact CiviCRM does not know the URL of the event on FB

Comment: Aah, got it: it's not liking the event on facebook, it's liking the page of the event on your site